# Prevent user to add same product twice in a cart of woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I want to prevent user to add same product twice in cart of Woocommerce in a same transaction, means once transaction is complete user can add that product into cart but at a same time user can add only one unit of that product into cart.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no 'action' hook before WooCommerce adds an item to the cart. But they have a 'filter' hook before adding to cart. That is how I use it:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'woo_custom_add_to_cart' );
function woo_custom_add_to_cart( $cart_item_data ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
    // Do nothing with the data and return
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

Comment: I think that this hook will limit cart to one product, the question is more about **max quantity of 1 per product**

Comment: When you add a product then there is an option to add maximum of one quantity for this product to cart. there is option "Sold individually" under inventory.